# python read text file return strange values

Tags: python, string, encode

When I read a text file with python, it returns strange values.

For example, I have this text in my file:

```
a_id
```

Python read result is:

```
'ÿþa\x00_\x00i\x00d\x00'
```

Comment: you made the textfile with BOM-UTF8 encoding ... (I think thats it ... ) ... open the file in your favorite (good) text editor (ie notepad++) and change it to normal ascii or normal utf8 ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley it's little endian UTF-16

Comment: hehe I knew it was something :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open) method in python has no encoding by default.

> open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None,
>   newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)

So doing this:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    print(f.readlines())
```

will result in:

```
['þÿ\x00a\x00_\x00i\x00d']
```

To fix that add the proper encoding, as such:

```
with open('test.txt', encoding='utf-16') as f:
    print(f.readlines())
```

which will give you:

```
['a_id']
```